# How does the GitHub pull request builder plugin know how not to build the jobs again and again?

Tags: git, jenkins

This should be a fairly simple question, but I may be missing something.

I am using the very nice GitHub pull request builder plugin. It works.

Question: Say I make a pull request. The job I have configured will run (as per the crontab) when it discovers the open pull request. Let's say it successfully runs and updates the comments in the pull request, etc.

Let's say I don't merge nor close the pull request. How does the plugin knows not to build the job over and over?

I have removed the successful Jenkins build and also the success message "Test PASSed.". It still, somehow, knows that it should not build the job again. How does it know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain of this - but I believe that the plugin is tracking the git commit ID on a per-pull request basis.  When the git commit ID changes on a particular pull request, it starts a new build.

I believe it will also be checking your commit comments, looking for the special ones like "retest this please" to initiate some action.  I think it may use the timestamp of the comments instead of a commit ID, but could be wrong there.